# systemd-networkd routing configuration with two interfaces

Tags: routing, systemd-networkd

I have a wired connection and a wireless connection configured in this way

```
[Match]
Name=eth01

[Network]
Address=10.0.0.120/24
Gateway=10.0.0.1

[Route]
Destination=0.0.0.0/0
Metric=1000
```

- I have tried 10.0.0.1 for Destination.
- I have tried leaving the `[Route]` section blank which by my reading of https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html
  should set that as the default route.

The wireless configuration is like this:

```
[Match]
Name=wlan0

[Network]
Address=10.0.0.129/24
Gateway=10.0.0.1

[Route]
Destination=0.0.0.0/0
Metric=2000
```

Again I have tried setting the Destination to the Gateway.

Whatever I try I get a routing like this :

```
default via 10.0.0.1 dev wlan0 proto static 
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth01 proto static 
10.0.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.129 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth01 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.120 
10.0.0.1 dev wlan0 proto static metric 2000
```

But I want the default route to go through the wired device unless the wired device is not present.

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like this:

```
[Match]
Name=eth01 # or wlan0

[Network]
Address=10.0.0.120/24 # or 10.0.0.129/24
RouteMetric=1000 # or 2000

# This section is probably optional
[Route]
Destination=10.0.0.1
Scope=link
PreferredSource=10.0.0.120 # or 10.0.0.129
Metric=1000 # or 2000

[Route]
# Destination=0.0.0.0/0 is implied when the option is not explicitly set
Gateway=10.0.0.1
PreferredSource=10.0.0.120 # or 10.0.0.129
Metric=1000 # or 2000
```

Comment: Would you please add some explanation around your solution so that I can understand why it is correct. I don't doubt that it is, and I thank you for it, but II like to know what I'm doing.

Comment: Well, `Gateway=` is essentially a shortcut of a `[Route]` section with `Destination=0.0.0.0/0`, which is the implied default when the option is unspecified. Therefore if you want to specify some more "details" for the default route (like `Metric=`), you can / should use a `[Route]` section instead of the shortcut. `PreferredSource=` is probably optional anyway if each interface has only one address configured.

Comment: Route that has a gateway/nexthop is called indirect route. For it to work you need to have a direct route that covers the gateway address. While the kernel-added prefix routes should technically work, the routes are not managed by networkd. IIIRC it will hiccup when trying to configure an indirect route when it does not manage a direct route that serves the former, that's why the additional `[Route]` section for `Destination=10.0.0.1`. `Scope=link` make sure that the section is processed / known before that of the default route.

Comment: The suggestion in the last paragraph is to avoid the prefix/subnet route to be added/managed by the kernel but by systemd instead (so that they can have metrics set as well). `10.0.0.0/24` covers `10.0.0.1`, so you can just replace the destination instead of adding yet another `[Route]` section.

Comment: Hm I find the `/32` breaks the network init. What's the idea there?

Comment: What do you mean by `breaks the network init`? Any log? (i.e. `journalctl -u systemd-networkd`)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I checked at the time. There was no error reported but still there was no connection. When I reset the prefix to 24 connection was restored. There may have been a concurrent issue coincidentally with my change but I didn't notice. Anyway I'll rerun the test  later today or tomorrow and get back to you then. thanks again.

Comment: Note that with `/32` used in `Address=` you'll need a `[Route]` section (of `Scope=link`) for `Destination=10.0.0.1` (Internet only) or `Destination=10.0.0.0/24` (Internet and LAN) in addition to one for `Gateway=10.0.0.1` (in which `Destination=0.0.0.0/0` is implied). Also check with `ip r` to confirm the configuration in effect.

Comment: Do you mean to have two `[Route]` sections in the same file?

Comment: Sure, just like the code block in my answer. One for the direct route to the router / LAN, one for the indirect default route to the "WAN" of/via the router.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128683/discussion-between-stephen-boston-and-tom-yan).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me. Clean and simple.

*/etc/systemd/network/eth.network*

```
[Match]
Name=eth01

[Network]
Address=10.0.0.120/24

[Route]
Gateway=10.0.0.1
Metric=1000
```

And

*/etc/systemd/network/wlan.network*

```
[Match]
Name=wlan0

[Network]
Address=10.0.0.129/24

[Route]
Gateway=10.0.0.1
Metric=2000
```

Gives

```
$ ip r
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth01 proto static metric 1000 
default via 10.0.0.1 dev wlan0 proto static metric 2000 
10.0.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.129 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth01 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.120
```